# Swagger JSON relative path

Tags: c#, asp.net, swagger, relative-path

In my ASP 4.6 application I have:

```
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Feature Toggle API V1"); });
```

When I run it on `localhost:5000/swagger/v1/swagger.json` it works fine but when I deploy it on a remote server that uses virtual directories for different applications `someserver/myapp/swagger/v1/swagger.json` it doesn't work.

What is the best practice in turning `app.UseSwaggerUI(c => { c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Feature Toggle API V1"); });`to a relative path that works on localhost as well as within a virtual directory?

Answer (score 30):

I was with this same problem
Try this:

```
        app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerEndpoint("v1/swagger.json", "V1 Docs");                
        });
```

Comment: This still works on .NET 6 and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this question is a bit old, but I had the same problem and found the answer in the ASP.NET Core documentation:

> If using directories with IIS or a reverse proxy, set the Swagger
>   endpoint to a relative path using the ./ prefix. For example,
>   ./swagger/v1/swagger.json. Using /swagger/v1/swagger.json instructs
>   the app to look for the JSON file at the true root of the URL (plus
>   the route prefix, if used). For example, use
>   http://localhost://swagger/v1/swagger.json instead
>   of
>   http://localhost:///swagger/v1/swagger.json.

Original link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio